# Building a Hashtag in Javascript without matching Anchor Names, BBCode or Escaped Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to convert any instances of a hashtag in a String into a linked URL:

#hashtag -> should have "#hashtag" linked.
This is a #hashtag -> should have "#hashtag" linked.
This is a [url=http://www.mysite.com/#name]named anchor[/url] -> should *not* be linked.
This isn&#39;t a pretty way to use quotes -> should *not* be linked.

Here is my current code:

```
String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
 return this.replace(/[^&][#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+(?!])/, function(t) {
  var tag = t.replace("#","")
  return t.link("http://www.mysite.com/tag/"+tag);
 });
};
```

Currently, this appears to fix escaped characters (by excluding matches with the amperstand), handles named anchors, but it doesn't link the #hashtag if it's the first thing in the message, and it seems to grab include the 1-2 characters prior to the "#" in the link.

Halp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
/(^|[^&])#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(?![A-Za-z0-9_\]-])/g
```

matches the hashtags in your example. Since JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind, it tries to either match the start of the string or any character except `&` before the hashtag. It captures the latter so it can later be replaced. It also captures the name of the hashtag.

So, for example:

```
subject.replace(/(^|[^&])#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(?![A-Za-z0-9_\]-])/g, "$1http://www.mysite.com/tag/$2");
```

will transform

```
#hashtag
This is a #hashtag and this one #too.
This is a [url=http://www.mysite.com/#name]named anchor[/url]
This isn&#39;t a pretty way to use quotes
```

into

```
http://www.mysite.com/tag/hashtag
This is a http://www.mysite.com/tag/hashtag and this one http://www.mysite.com/tag/too.
This is a [url=http://www.mysite.com/#name]named anchor[/url]
This isn&#39;t a pretty way to use quotes
```

This probably isn't what `t.link()` (which I don't know) would have returned, but I hope it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open-source Ruby gem to do this sort of thing (hashtags and @usernames) called [twitter-text](http://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-rb).  You might get some ideas and regexes from that, or try out [this JavaScript port](http://github.com/rubymaverick/twitter-text-js).

Using the JavaScript port, you'll want to just do:

```
var linked = TwitterText.auto_link_hashtags(text, {hashtag_url_base: "http://www.mysite.come/tag/"});
```

Comment: This is great for Twitter, but we're not using Twitter. We'll take a look at the codebase though, thanks.

Comment: while the library is designed to work with tweets, it'll link up hashtags in any text, and you can point the generated URLs wherever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Tim, your solution was *almost* perfect. Here's what I ended up using:

```
subject.replace(/(^| )#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(?![A-Za-z0-9_\]-])/g, "$1<a href=\"http://www.roleplaygateway.com/tag/$2\">#$2</a>");
```

The only change is the first conditional, changed it to match the beginning of the string **or** a space character. (I tried \s, but that didn't work at all.)